# Xcode 6 without Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am struggling to remove storyboards from Xcode6, I have tried the following questions :

[Xcode 5 without Storyboard and ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234172/xcode-5-without-storyboard-and-arc) and [Xcode 6 - Template without Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973521/xcode-6-template-without-storyboards)

But the output I get by following the above approaches is :

[image: Output in iOS 8 Simulator]

I have removed Main.storyboard file, removed entries of launch image and storyboard from info.plist.

I am using Objective-C. How can I adjust the view frame to the whole iPhone screen ?

here is the code I am using in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];

ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[window setRootViewController:viewController];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

[self setWindow:window];
return YES;
```

Comment: make empty application first

Comment: then add your views in it

Comment: This isn't caused by whether or not you're using storyboards. If you  want the view controller to take up the whole screen on 4 inch devices, you have to include the 4 inch launch image.

Comment: @N.A where can I create an Empty application in Xcode 6. Did you say: New Project -> Other -> Empty ?

Comment: yes New Project -> Other -> Empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put Default-568h@2x to your app bundle with dimension 1136x568. You can assign launch images using xcode catalog assets alternatively.

Comment: I haven't tried your solution yet, but can you please explain how is launch image related to rootViewController's window frame

Comment: This worked, please explain why is it so ?

Comment: In the image at top, the black part in window and white part is viewcontroller's view. Adding Default-568h@2x in your bundle tells Xcode that your app supports 4inch screen so it adjust views for it. Otherwise it keep your default layout to old 3.7 inch screen size and show black window top and down.

Comment: by separate launch images iOS recognizes whether your app is optimised to use new screen of newly released device or not.