# Cannot access UIImage class without importing UIKit.h in Xcode 6?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import, uiimage

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FaceObject : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;

@end
```

Xcode gives an error saying "unknown type name 'UIImage' unless I import UIKit.h, but in Xcode 5 i would have not gotten this error and did not need to import UIKit -- is there any explanation for this? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Check your PCH, clean or deep clean your project, erase derived data, quit and relaunch Xcode... There are many cases where Xcode loses its "import chain".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 6 no longer includes a .pch file by default. In previous versions, that file included the UIKit import (more info here - [Why isn't ProjectName-Prefix.pch created automatically in Xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6)).

Answer (score 8):

In 2015 -- still getting this error. I always forget to include

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

That should take care of it.