# Protocol Buffers in xcode 6 Mac 10.9

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have been researching how to make a demo on Protocol Buffers in iOS
I found this tutorial recommended by a lot of people:https://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers

I use 10.9 Mac version and xcode 6 with command-line tool installed.

I have followed this tutorial and downloaded **protobuf-2.6.0** and get some problem in **"Project Integration"** from step 2 to step 6. 
I don't understand how to do it in step 2 and I can't find **/Classes/ProtocolBuffers.h** in step 3. Also in step 4 and 5. Can anyone help me explain cleary this tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

you can find your the ProtocolBuffers.h in ProtocolBuffers-2.2.0-Source ▸ objectivec ▸ Classes.

In step2, 
first you create a workspace and add you current project to your workspace, and then add the ProtocolBuffers.xcodeproj to the workspace which is in the ProtocolBuffers-2.2.0-Source ▸ objectivec.

you can see here about how to add a existing project to the workspace, hence, your current project can't be opened when you add it.

*https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Adding_an_Existing_Project_to_a_Workspace.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009934-CH1-SW1*

and in xCode 6, there is no pch file, you can get your help here:
*[Why isn't ProjectName-Prefix.pch created automatically in Xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6)*