# How to import openCV into iOS 8 project

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, xcode6

I want to use openCV in my iOS 8 App. But there is a problem. I`ve updated my xCode to version 6.0.1 and there is my problem:

I imported openCV using this easy tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/hello/hello.html#opencvioshelloworld

After update everything crashes on the 2nd step: "Open the file named NameOfProject-Prefix.pch ..." there is no file with .pch suffix in my project.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Just include <opencv2/opencv.h> directly in the C++ classes or Objective-C++ classes that use them directly. Also see [Why isn't ProjectName-Prefix.pch created automatically in Xcode 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6).

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I need to get OpenCV working in the latest version as well.  I'll trace your steps.  If you got it working, a little help would be appreciated.  :-)  OK.  Actually, I have already included these steps...my issue is not with an application, but with a Universal Framework.  This script will not work and I have no clue why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I struggled with that also but i finally solved it.

Just add

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

to every header where you need it. Don't forget to rename your classes from **.m** to **.mm** to make it run. To use the framework in your c++ files just include it.

As Joe mentioned, have a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6).

Happy coding!

Comment: or you could add custom PCH file into project