# Xcode 6.1 Precompiled Headers

Tags: xcode6

In Xcode 6.1, creating a new project does not create a precompiled header file using the single view iOS project template. If I add one manually, any definitions in the pch file are not available in any other source files.

I've looked at many threads and questions and tried cleaning, re-buiding, re-starting, deleting derived data and manually removing the CACHE_ROOT/SharedPrecompileHeaders folder. All to no avail, though.

Some info suggests ticking to include in targets, but this is disabled for pch and other header files now.

See comment below.

Comment: Hi @Nick, I faced some other issues related to yours. Can you help me how can I manually remove CACHE_ROOT/SharedPrecompileHeaders folder. It has the path var/folders/49/..... and I can't find it

Comment: Hi @pf2707. I hope this answer will enable you to find the correct place - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12823466/2070111 - it should tell you the exact CACHE_ROOT for your project and then you can move to it and remove the headers.

Comment: Thank @Nick, I find out the solution. There's command line to do it, just type  cd /private/var/folders, and can delete file in this folder

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't ProjectName-Prefix.pch created automatically in Xcode 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6)

Comment: DanSkeel obviously has too much time! The 'other' question accepted an answer that didn't actually answer the question, but was a rant - the real answer is buried about fourth down, so I had given up before I got to the answer, it turns out, even though I had read it before posting. For someone actually looking for the answer quickly (which is what I use SO for rather than to waste my time trolling), my question is more useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried adding the path of the pch file?

Go to `your project -> Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 6.0 Language`.

Under it, set the following things:

- Precompile Prefix Header: Set it to YES
- Prefix Header: Set the path to the pch file

**Update 2018/09/23**: In Xcode10 it is under `Apple Clang - Language`

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, I fell down some stairs and have been a bit pre-occupied! I hadn't noticed this. You are absolutely correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem Nick. I hope you are ok now and it was a minor accident. Take care! :)

Comment: note that you cannot add this setting for the first time from within a project opened with podfile (suffix xcworkspace).  I believe initially it must be added to the actual xcode project (suffix xcodeproj).