# Where should I set KApiKey, KApiSecret, KToken and KURL in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, api, sdk, key

I am integrating my application code with Payeezy iOS SDK. but could not find the file to set KApiKey, KApiSecret, KToken and KURL

```
#define KApiKey    @"test_apikey_bA8hIqpzuAVW6itHqXsXwSl6JtFWPCA0"
#define KApiSecret @"test_apitsecret_YmI4YzA1NmRkZmQzMzA1ZmIZjYzwMWIzZThkMWU2NGRjZmI4OWE5NGRiMzM4NA=="
#define KToken     @"test_merchant_token_fdoa-a480ce8951daa73262734cf102641994c1e55e7cdf4c02b6"
#define KURL       @"https://api-cert.payeezy.com/v1/transactions"
```

Please let me know the file name to set the parameter ? do you have any application that I can use for Authorize Capture and Purchase void ?

Comment: Put those in the one file that needs them.

Answer (score 0):

Either put them in a file that needs them, or if you want it throughout the app, you would put them in a prefix header.

To create a precompiled header, first make a .pch file, add those defines, and follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26971800/3197253) to add the pch to your project.

Comment: How do I initialize? and pass parameter to authorize payment

Answer (score 0):

You can set these parameters in the ViewController.m file in the payeezy sdk. You can also do it in the client specific .m  file if you are doing custom implementation.

Initialize PayeezySDK object with KApiKey, KApiSecret, KToken and KURL like below

```
// initialize Payeezy object with key,token and secret value
PayeezySDK* myClient = [[PayeezySDK alloc]initWithApiKey:KApiKey apiSecret:KApiSecret merchantToken:KToken url:KURL];
```

Following is the link to the payeezy integration for ios
https://github.com/payeezy/payeezy_ios/blob/master/guide/payeezy_iOS_SDK042015.pdf

Comment: thanks Nilesh. Code is working fine. I am able to post my transaction for Auth Capture.