# Altering "Build Settings" to include a prefix header in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios8, xcode6, precompiled-headers, build-settings

I'm presently taking an iOS development course and I'm working with Objective-C for this portion of the course. My current lesson involves altering a Prefix header, which wasn't created when I started this project. I created one manually following the guidance given in this post on the topic.

[Why isn't ProjectName-Prefix.pch created automatically in Xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6)

In "Build Settings" under Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language, I changed "Precompile Prefix Header" from "No" to "Yes", but I'm unable to figure out how to specify the filename under "Debug and Release". I've tried clicking, command+clicking, option+clicking, control+clicking to no avail on "Prefix Header/Debug" and "Prefix Header/Release". What do I need to do?

I know there are sharply divided opinions on this topic, but all I'm trying to do is move forward on my lesson.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I did not click over far enough. There were 3 columns: "Resolved", "MyApp", and "iOS Default". I clicked on column under "MyApp" and I was able to type in the filename.