# Custom NSLog without precompiled header

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog, pch

Since Xcode 6 and the [introduction of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194968/1352169), there is no need for precompiled headers anymore. I have always been using a custom logging method which also logs the file, method and line number it was on. This method was defined in the precompiled header. Where should I define the method now we shouldn't use them anymore, without me having to define it in a bunch of files?

```
#define YBLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: You can put the `#define` in any .h file you want, so long as you explicitly include/import the .h into the .m that uses the macro.

Comment: @HotLicks Any way I only have to define it once?

Comment: You only have to define it once.  But without the PCH mechanism you need to include it in every file that uses the macro.

Answer (score 2):

Your `#define` have a little mistake.

You are define `YBLog(fmt,...)` to `YBLog` itself. You need to write `NSLog` instead of `YBLog` in the macro definition.

You need to define it like:

```
#define YBLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to access the same on so many files, you have two option.

1. Add a `pch` file by yourself and add the declaration in it (I'm doing the same)
2. Define it in a header file and include it anywhere you want

Comment: Silly me. Thanks for that, but I'll remove it from the OP since it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: @yoeriboven: I have updated my answer for answering your question

Answer (score 0):

Create a common.h file and put it in there. 
Import it where necessary.