# How to import a Cocoa Touch Framework written in Swift to a .pch file?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a Swift framework which I want to import in every class I make in my Swift project. I don't want to have to type the `import` statement manually, and everywhere. How can I do this?

In Objective-C this would be the same as putting one `#import` statement in the pre-compiled header (.pch file).

**What I tried**

- Create a new Xcode project with the Cocoa Touch Framework template, write all my code in Swift.
- All my extensions and methods in the framework have the `public` keyword.
- Added the framework's `.xcodeproj` to my app's Xcode project.
- Add the `.framework` in Target Dependencies.
- Create a .pch file in my app project (also written in Swift).
- Wrote `<FrameworkName/FrameworkName.h>` in the .pch file. This doesn't solve the problem, and kinda doesn't make sense, because I don't really import anything in the `FrameworkName.h` inside the framework project.

Comment: Is it a Swift-only project or mixed ObjC-Swift?

Comment: The framework is Swift-only, the app is also Swift-only.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no solution at the moment. You can't auto import a framework in all Swift classes, like was possible in ObjC with a PCH file. The only solution I know is to import the framework in the bridge file, then is accessible everywhere, but in a Swift-only project you don't have this solution available.

Answer (score 3):

You can add .pch file manually and then you can import your common files in your .pch file. for more info see below link

[Add new .pch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6)

see in this image[image]

Comment: I created a .pch from my project, but how do I import my Swift framework from it?

Comment: @Matt Please see the given link who helps you because every step is defined there.

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood. I'm not just asking for how to create a .pch file to pre-import all the files that are within the same project. I'm asking for how to import a Cocoa Touch *Framework* that I built in pure Swift, and how to import that in the .pch so I don't have to import it in every file. Note that if a framework is built using pure Swift, there isn't a single `.h` file for the whole framework.

Comment: @Matt You can #import UIKit and see my edited answer