# Xcode 7 not using compiled header for error warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I upgraded to Xcode 7 yesterday and I'm getting a bunch of errors from Xcode. The program compiles / runs fine, but when programming it says things like `No known class method for selector...`, `Use of undeclared identifier`, `No visible @interface for...`, or `Receiver type '...' for instance message is a forward declaration`.

All of these errors, I assume, are coming up because it isn't using my precompiled header (`*.pch`) which includes the files needed for it to know about those classes.

How do I tell Xcode to look at the precompiled header?

I'm only using Objective-C.

Comment: What are the classes/methods it's complaining about?

Comment: This answer explains how to add the `.pch` file to your project. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24258165/725628

Comment: @EmilioPelaez thanks for the link. I've added it to LLVM 7.0 but I'm still getting the errors. I've Cleaned the Build Folder and still nothing.

Comment: @trojanfoe the files are my classes (things like `CurrentUser`) and a few MagicalRecord methods.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I take that back. Just Cleaned Build Folder again and it started working. Thanks! If you'll add that as an answer, I'll accept it. It'd be worth mentioning that Xcode 7 uses a new LLVM and thus needs to have the header added again.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez can you add your comment as a question? I'll accept it as soon as you do.