# iWatcher-Prefix.pch.pch: No such file or directory

Tags: objective-c

I have this warning :

while processing /Users/myName/Desktop/myApp/AppRight.framework/AppRight(GrNativeCrashEvent.o):
warning: /Users/gryphonet/workspace/ios/iWatcher/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/iWatcher-Prefix-clslxlldlvbjdmgkugmxtoospkbr/iWatcher-Prefix.pch.pch: No such file or directory

I try this solution but its not work

[Why isn't ProjectName-Prefix.pch created automatically in Xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6)

And I try to add iWatcher-Prefix.pch.pch file

[image]

[image]

but still have this warning.