# Swift Objective-C header is not found when archiving the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

I am trying to add Swift class in one objective-c file for which I had to add *-Swift.h file in my objc file. While the project works fine in debug mode but when I try to archive my app it's throwing error saying that particularly that *-Swift.h file is not found. I tried many solutions but none of them worked. Then I got this question on apple website which is exactly the same problem but his solution which was to set precompile prefix header to YES also did not work for me. (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7512).

I do understand that this header is generated in derived data and build process for debug and archive is different but nothing is working in my case.

I have one framework inside which my app target is located.
I am adding the header in my objc as `#import "My_Project-Swift.h"`

I am using XCode 10.

Comment: Can you try importing swift file inside prefix.pch file, it'd work.

Comment: sorry did not get you. can you elaborate ?

Comment: You can find or create one prefix.pch header file and just import swift file there.Please follow this link to create one .pch header file https://stackoverflow.com/a/24524692/4126683

Comment: i added it. did not solve problem. now its showing the same error in the created .pch file

Comment: ok build is succeeded but the error is there. how can that happen?

Comment: Not sure regarding the error, maybe cleaning derive data will resolve the error or someone else could answer this perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

1. In Xcode: Product -> Clean (Shift+Cmd+K)
2. Delete Derived Data
3. Change **Precompiled Prefix Header** to **YES** in the target build settings
4. Close Xcode
5. Open Xcode
6. Archive